# Difference between rtl8821ae and rtl8723be: if I install rtl8723be what will happen?

Tags: wireless, realtek-wireless

I'm using Lenovo-320 Ideapad a6-AMD processor. I'm frequently facing Wi-Fi automatic connecting and disconnecting issues.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
if I install rtl8723be what will happen?
```

Nothing; absolutely nothing.

Although I am sure that there are differences in each driver related to the specific chipset, the main difference that is relevant here is the mechanism by which driver modules load or not.

A driver will be called up and loaded when the system finds a pci.id or usb.id (and others not relevant here), that is explicitly listed in the driver. You can see this with:

```
modinfo rtl8821ae
```

From my machine:

```
<snip>
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008821sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008812sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

So any device with the pci.id of 10ec:8821 or 10ec:8812 will be claimed by the driver rtl8821ae.

Compare rtl8723be:

```
modinfo rtl8723be
```

From my machine:

```
<snip>
alias:          pci:v000010ECd0000B723sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

So any device with the pci.id of 10ec:b723 will be claimed by rtl8723be.

There are, in fact, a very few devices that are claimed by two, and in one case, three (!!!) drivers, but your device isn’t one of them.

You can find the pci.id for your device with the command:

```
lspci -nnk
```

And you can narrow down the results to your wireless device with:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
```